# Why does my local.xml load javascript repeatedly using addItem

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, local.xml, skin

I am attempting to load a javascript file in my custom skin using the following code in local.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
   <default>
        <!-- remove some things that NKI doesn't use -->
        <reference name="head">
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/nki.js</script></action>

        </reference>
   </default>
</layout>
```

Why does it first attempt to look in the base theme skin directory, then my directory?

I see it's attempting to load

- https://dev.nursingknowledge.org/skin/frontend/base/default/js/nki.js (404)
- https://dev.nursingknowledge.org/skin/frontend/base/default/js/nki.js
  (404 - yes, twice)
- https://dev.nursingknowledge.org/skin/frontend/NKI/NKI/js/nki.js (actual location)

The file exists in `/var/www/skin/frontend/NKI/NKI/js/nki.js`

I am a little confused. Maybe my method for loading using local.xml is outdated.  Any suggestions?  Maybe I have a setting wrong in admin?

EDIT: added **local.xml** location

> app/design/frontend/NKI/default/layout/local.xml

Comment: can you please update your question with `local.xml` file path?

Comment: I've added the location of layout.xml.

Comment: its `local.xml` not `layout.xml`. I Edited your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your **local.xml** file is in wrong path. It should be inside

```
app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml
```

In your case

```
app/design/frontend/NKI/NKI/layout/local.xml
```

In **local.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
   <default>
        <!-- remove some things that NKI doesn't use -->
        <reference name="head">
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/nki.js</name></action>
        </reference>
   </default>
</layout>
```

It should be `<name>` instead of `<script>` tag

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Those were some spot-on suggestions. I made those changes, and things magically started working.

Comment: Glad to know that its working fine